# Using SignalR with Windows service as Server and .NET application as client

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

After posting [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324351/solution-for-simple-grid-computing-in-local-network) about the best way to call server methods from clients and clients method from server using C#, I'm trying to start using SignalR but I'm not familiar at all with the web programming.

I would like to use a Windows service as SignalR server and .NET Windows applications as clients. I saw in some other questions asked 1 year ago (like this [console app example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140164/signalr-console-app-example/12058856#12058856) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004375/signalr-how-to-call-net-client-method-from-server/16017366#16017366)) that the best solution would be to use Owin self-host on the server-side, and a HubProxy in the client applications.

Is it still the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is WCF not a good option for this?

Comment: It seems very easy to call server's methods from clients and clients' methods from the server with SignalR. And I can even host the server in a console application instead of a service. I have never used WCF, do you think it can be easier?

Comment: Probably it is better documented in WCF http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF . WCF has been around for many years already.

Comment: Thank you, WCF seems to be a very good solution for what I need to develop! I think I will keep starting with SignalR as it seems easier to learn and startup with (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15360416/972604), but now I know that both are the best solutions.

Comment: AFAIK (not an expert about WCF at all), in order to implement a proper full duplex with WCF you would need your client to listen for connections on a port. Maybe this is perfectly fine with you, but if it's not then with SignalR you do not have such requirement.